# Kubernetes Pod crashing after adding jar

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes

I have a Scala Spark application.  After building the application with Maven from Jenkins it creates a jar file. I am adding the jar file to a destination defined inside my Dockerfile.

Dockerfile created:

```sh
FROM semantive/spark:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
ADD . /usr/src/app
ADD target/*.jar /usr/src/app/apps.jar
```

When I am creating a pod from the image built by the Dockerfile it goes into the CrashLoopBackOff state.
But when I remove the `ADD` command from the Dockerfile it is working fine and the Kubernetes containers are running. Any idea if the `ADD` command is incorrect?  The jar file is present in the target folder of Jenkins.

Comment: That superficially seems okay (I'd usually prefer `COPY` to `ADD` but it shouldn't make a difference here).  Can you `docker run` the built image without Kubernetes?  Is there anything interesting in its `kubectl logs`?

Comment: yes I am able to run the docker container with docker image. But kubernetes pod is crashing, nothing as such in the logs also I did try kubectl describe pod, but nothing is there

Comment: I re-ran it now it is showing some error.
bash: bin/spark-class: No such file or directory

Comment: in which case it sounds like you'd want to remove `WORKDIR /usr/src/app/`, or find out what the upstream image had its WORKDIR set to and restore the working directory at the end of your dockerfile

Comment: Hey, thanks man it works, in the base image itself the WORKDIR was set, I removed the WORKDIR from my Dockerfile as I only creating directory and copying the jar to it.